# Epimorphisms and Algebras

Tags: category-theory

Just a quick question. Suppose a monad on $\mathbf{Set}$ (in particular monad's endofunctor preserves epimorphisms), are epimorphisms in the category of algebras also surjective?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A well-known example is the category of rings, in which epimorphisms may fail to be surjective (e.g. $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$).

What is true is that, for any monad on $\mathbf{Set}$, the *regular* epimorphisms in the category of algebras are precisely the surjective homomorphisms.